How to change Windows 11 cmd console (Windows Terminal) menu language?
Please see screenshots: some of the menus are in Japanese, and one is in Polish.
How can I change language of all those menus to Polish? I have a Japanese keyboard layout installed, and I need it, so "just uninstall" is not an option.




Keyboard layout aside, do you have any other regional settings set to Japanese (like the region itself, or the non-Unicode locale)?

@grawity even if I have I don't know. All the other apps are in either Polish or English, for example Control Panel is English and Explorer is in Polish. Time and date formats are Polish.

The program in your screenshots is Windows Terminal – it's neither Cmd (which has no interface by itself) nor Windows console (which is the old interface for Cmd).
Press Ctrl, or open  from your menu, then change the language in the "Startup" section:

Alternatively, after opening "Settings", press the  icon in the corner to directly edit settings.json in a text editor and add "language": "en-US" in the top-level section.
